# Extending javax.mail.Authenticator causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, class, email, noclassdeffounderror

My app can send out an email without using an email `Intent` or having user interaction. I followed this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/394933) to achieve this. Everything has been working fine until recently when the app started crashing when it tried to send an email. The email sender class, which I called `Mail`, is defined like this...

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    public Mail() {
        // some initialization code
    }
    public void send() {
        // some more code
    }
}
```

For some reason now, whenever I try to create an instance of an object that extends `javax.mail.Authenticator`, I get `NoClassDefFoundError`. If I remove the `javax.mail.Authenticator` extension, I don't get an error when trying to create an instance of `Mail`. I also have all the necessary jars included (mail.jar, activation.jar, additional.jar). Does anyone know what's causing this problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this problem happens after an ADT update you should look at [this post](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17).

You have in fact to create a **libs** folder to put all your libraries and the build path will be managed by Eclipse.

Comment: Ah yes this did start happening after I updated the ADT in Eclipse.